Internet is connected but programs don't see it, reset caused net to fail with VPN
To start, I have Windows 11. Today internet on my laptop randomly stopped working while I was using it. Doesn't matter to which WiFi I connect - it connects and computer says there are no problems with connection, yet I can't browse the net or download anything - as if programs don't see the connection.
I've tried the following commands:
netsh advfirewall reset, netsh winsock reset, ipconfig /release, ipconfig /renew, ipconfig /flushdns, netsh winsock reset catalog, netsh int ipv4 reset reset.log, netsh int ipv6 reset reset.log,
but I think netsh winsock reset is what helped internet to start working again.
It helped but I bumped into another problem. Internet started working but now, when I turn on my VPN, internet stops working and it is as if I'm offline. I tried netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface "Local Area Connection" mtu=1492 store=persistent with my MTU and interface but it didn't help.
While I was trying to fix the VPN problem on my own (checking drivers, etc.), the WiFi connection thing happened once again - programs stopped seeing the connection (did netsh winsock reset, started working again, but the VPN problem happened again).
It is not the Internet, it is not the VPN (everything works perfectly on other devices). I've tried all the commands, reinstalled drivers, updated drivers, did network reset, reinstalled the server that I have for VPN and reinstalled the VPN client (still works on other devices, but not on this computer), rebooted laptop several times, I don't have any AntiVirus, I checked the firewall thing and I don't think that's the problem either.
Don't know why the connection was lost, and I think it might happen again. Also the VPN thing bothers me as I use it every day. Really don't know what to try at this point...

First, don't tell us "I tried everything at this link", instead, list each and every command you have run. Don't tell us "after one of these various commands something changed", do tell us the specific command that caused the change. "I don't know" is a valid answer, but take that as a warning that it is good to pay closer attention next time, and don't just run a bunch of commands. Second, it feels like you're just running commands without understanding what you are doing. You messed up your VPN settings: did you try uninstalling and reinstalling the VPN client?

Please EDIT your post to make it more clear and precise in the information it gives and in how it presents that information.

@music2myear Thank you so much for the recommendation, I edited the post. I know what each command does as I read about them before using them, but I'm a bit lost with all this situation - that is why I tried all of them. Yes, I did reinstall the VPN server and the VPN client - the problem is still somewhere in my computer and its connection, VPN works perfectly on other devices.

@ulyana - The VPN works as expected on another device?

@Ramhound - Yes, everything works great on other devices. The VPN on this computer makes the WI-FI disconnect. I think it has something to do with the reset commands I used.
